# Java NIO. An effective solution for simulating a basic download application or not?

Tags: java, nio

I'm trying to simulate a simple download application by copying a file like `myBook.txt` and saving it as `newBook.txt` within the same Java Package.

I've managed to get it working on my workstation but how would I go about getting it to work on another? The path's that I supply will be different up until the project name e.g. `"SimpleDownloadCentre\\..."`

```
private final String SOURCE_PATH = "C:\\Users\\...\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\"
            + "SimepleDownloadCentre\\src\\simpledownloadcentre\\"
            + "myBook.txt";

private final String DESTINATION_PATH = "C:\\Users\\...\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\"
            + "SimepleDownloadCentre\\src\\simpledownloadcentre\\"
            + "newBook.txt";

public void startDownload() {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            String destination = DESTINATION_PATH;
            String source = SOURCE_PATH;

            fis = new FileInputStream(source);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destination);

            FileChannel fci = fis.getChannel();
            FileChannel fco = fos.getChannel();

            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

            while (true) {
                try {
                    int read = fci.read(buffer);
                    if (read == -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    buffer.flip();

                    fco.write(buffer);

                    buffer.clear();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.err.println("ERROR: unable to read block");
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: file not found");
        } finally {
            try {
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("ERROR: unable to close file channel");
            }
        }
    }
```

Is Java NIO the wrong approach for the solution I'm after?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NIO is not a problem, though it won't help much more than using IO.

What I would do is:

- Use a bigger buffer e.g. 32 KB.
- Use a direct buffer (its faster than using a heap one in this case)
- Use a Socket connection to simulate a network/download connection.

You can do all this (except the direct buffer) using plain IO of course.

If you don't need the Sockets and just want to transfer data I would use transferTo/transferFrom to perform the copy.

In summary: Using NIO is not a bad or good idea.

Comment: Thanks. +1.  Anyone suggestions for making the application portable?  The paths I have supplied are absolute paths that will only work on my workstation.

Comment: You could use the `System.getProperty("user.dir");` to get the user's home directory. You could pass the source and destination path as arguments to the `startDownload` method.

Comment: Thanks.  `System.getProperty("user.dir");` is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Your copy loop is incorrect. It can lose data if write() doesn't write the entire buffer. It should read as follows:

```
while ((read = in.read(buffer)) >= 0 || buffer.position() > 0)
{
  buffer.flip();
  out.write(buffer);
  buffer.compact();
}
```